# Removing records with a zero amount in a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying to figure out a way to remove records from a Hashmap where the amount is equal to zero.  I found some code online and tried this below.  From looking at the log it isn’t working.   Is there something missing in keyset filter that I am missing?   Do I need to create a new Hashmap that contains the results of this that only shows amounts?

```
            logger.info("Size of the caseTotal before processing is " + caseTotals.size()) ;
           
           caseTotals.keySet().removeAll(
                                           caseTotals.entrySet().stream()
                      .filter(a->a.getValue().equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
                              .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
           
           
           caseTotals.forEach((k,v)->logger.info("case number: " + k + ", totalAmount: " + v.toString()));      
           logger.info("Size of the caseTotal after processing is " + caseTotals.size()) ;
```

Log

2024-01-26 07:45:26,244[0;39m: Processing the Monthly Fund Expense Report process job.  Loading the processed month journal entries

[30m2024-01-26 07:45:32,537[0;39m: Size of the caseTotal before processing is 1573384

[30m2024-01-26 07:45:32,683[0;39m: case number: 494-434824, totalAmount: 98.08

[30m2024-01-26 07:45:32,684[0;39m: case number: 022-119172, totalAmount: 0.00

[30m2024-01-26 07:45:32,684[0;39m: case number: 263-437492, totalAmount: 0.00

Comment: I suspect the zero value has different scale, try writing `a->a.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple big problems here.

### You are using BigDecimal for finance stuff

This is bad. You should be using `long`, or possibly something like [joda-money](https://www.joda.org/joda-money/). BigDecimal is better than `double` but not by a lot. Specifically, BigDecimal doesn't solve the unsolvable problem, which is that you simply cannot apply division in currency systems without rules about how to divide the remainders (you can't 'divide' 4 cents by 3 accounts, not even BigDecimal can do that, you need explicit code for **every** situation where it comes up). And as long as you're not dividing, `long` works better, it's a lot simpler.

As a very specific example of why BigDecimal bad, you've made a subtle mistake here: **`.equals()` for BigDecimal does not mean what you think it means**. Specifically, 2 BD values whose exact value is 0, **do not have to be equal**, because BDs take 'scale' into account. In other words, `0.00` is not equal to `0.000`:

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2);
BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(3);
System.out.println(a == b); // false. of course.
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // also false.
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); // 0. What the....
```

Presumably this isn't the time to completely refactor how your app works, but **know that you are going to run into all sorts of problems until you fix it properly**, which is to eliminate BD. Use `long`, and store the atomic finance unit in them (so, if it costs €1.04, that article will have a `long price;` whose value is `104`). Every place where fractionals come in, write code that is *custom designed to deal with that precise situation as the bank / app / situation dictates it should go*.

Example:

- You are a bank; you have joint accounts where each joint account holder is deemed to be responsible for the whole thing. The bank has an option to terminate such an account, in which case the money in it is divided equally amongst all joint holders. Let's say $1.04 is in the account right now. It has 3 owners.

The correct code in the bank is definitely not:

- Take 1.04, divide it by 3 using BigDecimal, add that to each joint holder's balance. This is wrong, because it crashes: You can't divide 1.04 by 3. Try it. You'll need to introduce a rounding error to do it, and the whole point of BD is to avoid rounding errors. If you're gonna introduce them right back in, you might as well just use `double` then!
- Take 1.04, divide it by 3 using BD, apply a bunch of rounding, store cents to the tenth decimal, and leave it like that. This *still* introduces a rounding error, and just kicks the can down the road. Joe has $12.2130123912309123 cents dollars in their account (as in, 12 dollars, 21 cents, and slightly less than a third of a cent to ridiculous detail). Joe wants to cancel their account and wants the remainder transferred to another bank. The other bank, naturally, does not allow you to transfer .30123912309123 cents, so, you have to write custom code to deal with fractions there. If you're going to end up with a system where custom code is needed, why not apply it 'at the source', so to speak? Much simpler all around.

Instead you'd do:

- The 1.04 is divided evenly amongst the joint owners; each gets 34 cents. That leaves 2 cents which cannot be divided. The bank generates some random numbers and uses those to determine 2 arbitrary joint holders who each get 1 cent.
- The 1.04 is divided evenly amongst the joint owners; each gets 34 cents. That leaves 2 cents which cannot be divided. The bank's Terms of Service state that in such cases the remainder goes to the bank, in favour of the bank. So, the bank keeps the 2 cents. Of course, had it been a negative amount, each of the joint holders would **lose** 35 cents, and the bank would keep 1 cent. Either way the bank gains. Failure to do it right leads some enterprising soul to repeatedly make joint accounts and terminate them, fleecing the bank for a few cents every time, they make billions until the bank tries to sue the silly programmers who decided to mess with BigDecimal.

### Okay, got the message. But I need this fixed now!

Well, step one is to know that **you must NEVER invoke equals here!** - or at least, you need to understand that equals does not mean what you think it means. The right way to check if 2 BD values are the same value is `a.compareTo(b) == 0`.

Secondly, this is a really inefficient/weird way to remove a bunch of values from a map that have a certain property. This is vastly more efficient:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(e.getValue()) == 0);
```

Comment: “BigDecimal is better than `double` but not by a lot.”  On the contrary;  it is substantially better.  Regardless of your point regarding division, BigDecimal will represent large values exactly and that is certainly a lot better than using double.  That aside, `entrySet()` is not needed here;  one can simply do `map.values().removeIf(v -> BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(v) == 0);`.

Comment: @VGR "A lot" is subjective. The point is, `long` beats BD. For many many reasons; it's not an absolute (long is better than BD for reasons A,B,C,D,E,F, and G; BD beats long for reason H and I - in general long is the right answer far more often than BD is, and in addition, _if_ BD beats long, generally joda-time is then an even better answer than BD would be) - but one of the reasons is what OP ran into here: That BD's equals method is not at all appropriate for finance values.